# Solr Query: replacing whitespace with +

Tags: java, solr

The application I'm working on uses solr to index and search entries. I've been reading a bit about the logic and syntax behind in. Currently there's a bit of code that I'm confuses me and I'm hoping someone can clear up why the person who wrote this bit of code did it the way they did.

```
trimmedSearchField = SolrQueryUtil.escapeQueryString(trimmedSearchField).replaceAll("\\s+", "+");
            String qString = "+(title:" + trimmedSearchField + "^100 OR description_t:" + trimmedSearchField + "^10 " +
                    "OR +" + trimmedSearchField +"^1)";
```

I'm just wanting bring attention to the .replaceAll method, why would we want to replace whitespace with +? My goal is to refactor a bit a search bar and I get better results ommitting the replaceAll call.

Example: two elements with the descriptions: "Helen of Troy" and "Helen from Troy" respectively. With replaceAll present, searching "Helen of Troy" will provide me with only the first element, with replaceAll removed, both will appear (which is what I want to occur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that .replaceAll() call is just encoding any series of consecutive whitespaces into a single '+', which mean 'required' in [lucene syntax (and Solr)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#+)

So it makes 'trimmedSearchField' mandatory in those fields.

Comment: The thing is that this isn't being passed through a url, it's being passed to solrj and now we have boolean operators appended to every word.